# React-native app whitescreen when in background for a longer time

Tags: ios, react-native, webview

Short description of our situation:
We have a react-native application which renders a website with react-native-webview (https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview)

Whenever our application is in the background for a longer time (mostly occures over night), the application results in a whitescreen when opening up the next day. This only really occures on iPhones - not on android devices / nor on iPads.

When the application goes to the background, we stop all polling tasks and the app isn't really doing anything till it comes to the foreground again.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this problem? Is this a general problem on iPhones with webviews?

We have a possible fix by really disabling the webview, when the app goes to the background (by not rendering the Webview once the appState goes to background). Still would be interesting to know where this comes from.

I'm thankful for any help!
Have a nice day.

Comment: Hi @Marc23481, did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I found this information with a possible solution: https://blog.embrace.io/bug-of-the-month-blank-webviews/

> They occur when web views fail or are killed by the OS. Normally, a process being killed would crash the application, but on iOS, WKWebViews have two additional processes: a content process and a networking process. These can be killed without affecting the main application process. You can provide a better user experience by deciding which web views should be reloaded upon failure and adding this functionality through the webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate callback on WKNavigationDelegate.

Haven't tried it out yet - but will.

**UPDATE:** this fixed all my problems!